# window.opener.jsNamespace is undefined in some version of MSIE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain

we have a the following web flow which fails on some MSIE agents:

- a page P1 from domain D1 creates an iframe on page P2 from domain D2
- P2 has a JavaScript w/ namespace jsNS & myMethod
- P2 creates a popup window on page P3 from domain D2
- P3 calls window.opener.jsNS.myMethod

window.opener refers to P2, which works fine in all the browsers we can test with, but we are seeing in production that a **few** MSIE agents are getting client-side JavaScript exceptions:

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'myMethod'
```

In this case, window.opener.jsNS is not null, but 'undefined'.

We have an alternate flow without popups for mobile/tablet devices which is seeing the same issue although with a slightly different error.

```
 TypeError: 'window.opener.jsNS' is null or not an object
```

jsNS is not null, but 'undefined' in this case as well.

In the mobile flow, the only difference we can think of is that the iframe P2 has jsNS embedded (vs. in an external js file), e.g.:

```
jsNS = {};
jsNS.myMethod = function() {return false;}
var P3 = window.open('', 'P3');
P3.focus();
```

This exception seem to affect different versions of MSIE from 8 to 10 with various packaging including Media Center PC, Tablet PC, etc. and we're unable to identify a pattern to them. Also, again, despite testing many different MSIE systems on our side, we'be been unable to reproduce this issue at all.

Does anyone have any idea on what type of MSIE setting or packaging or environment could cause this exception for some users?
Any suggestion on how this could be troubleshooted further with affected users would be welcome as well.

Comment: At first glance, it seems like either the JS hasn't been loaded by the time the popup requests it or you're running into same origin policy, though the latter should theoretically be 100% repro.

Comment: Couldn't that error happen if the user does whatever makes P3 show up, and then subsequently closes the P1 browser tab?

Comment: @Pointy you are absolutely right, but many of our users swear they have not closed P1 and have sent us screenshots of the error message with P1 in the background so something else seems to be going on with some MSIE browsers...

Comment: Hmm... well, there's always the possibility that they've re-opened P1 afterwards. Perhaps you've considered that too however. I've never seen IE "forget" about the "opener" relationship, but I wouldn't describe my experience extensive with that sort of thing.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté P2 creates P3, so it would have to be loaded for P3 to exist. Our flow is also multi-step and takes a while to get through so this sounds highly unlikely anyhow and should affect all browsers randomly if it were the case.

Comment: My bad, I've only noticed that both P2 and P3 belong to the same domain after commenting.